# error : { "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI", "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox." }

Tags: outlook

I am new with the "outlook" api. i want to get all calender event,contact and mail from "outlook account".

but i does not get appropriate result with "outlook" account its working fine with "office365" account

i follow [this](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php) documentation for get all required data
and i create application for getting data from [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

but every time when i login with my outlook account it's give me an error like this.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into the same problem and found an explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/use-outlook-rest-api#OutlookRESTCaution). It appears we're going to have to wait for the accounts to be enabled unless you request a testing account as described in the link. Confirmed the same results when using the non-enabled account in the [Outlook Oauth Sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/).

**From the first link**

- Because enabling mailboxes on Outlook.com for the Outlook REST API happens over a period of time, your existing Outlook.com account may take a while to get enabled. To test your app accessing data on Outlook.com mailboxes that have already been enabled, you can request a new, enabled Outlook.com developer preview account by emailing outlookdev@microsoft.com.
- If your app accesses Outlook.com mailbox data, it should handle scenarios where the user's mailbox has not yet been enabled for the Outlook REST API. In such situations, when you make a REST request, you would get an error like the following:

  - HTTP error: 404
  - Error code: MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI or MailboxNotSupportedForRESTAPI
  - Error message: “REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox.

Comment: Robert, do you know of any timeline when we can expect our accounts to be enabled?

Comment: Sorry @clark173, I can't find any hard dates, wish I could. Only info says they are enabling as fast as they can in waves. Can't be enabled manually. [30 sep](https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial/issues/2#issuecomment-144262077)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**

Click the Below Link :

https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/?code=M657b8bab-e543-f849-134c-0a2f85179a67&state=17661047-2a14-4c90-9edd-0119f841b559

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3 :**

[image]

**Step 4 :**

[image]

**Step 5 :**

[image]