# Outlook RestAPI is not working

Tags: python, django, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

Outlook restapi is not working

I am folllowing the doc https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/python

I got a developer preview account (devxxxx@outlook.com) from outlook and I created an app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

So my idea is to view contacts of people from their outlook account by connecting to this app through oauth2.

When I connect with the same account (devxxxx@outlook.com), I am getting correct credentials(like access token, token_id, etc.) and I can communicate with rest API through these credentiasls and is working fine, I can able to viw the contacts.

But when I try to connect through different account (ex: geo.jacobxxx@outlook.com) as usual I am getting correct credentials(like access token, token_id, etc.), But I am not able to play with rest API, I am getting error response as

```
404: {"error":{"code":"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI","message":"REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox."}}
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error : { "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI", "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox." }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093363/error-code-mailboxnotenabledforrestapi-message-rest-api-is-not-yet)

Comment: No I already got developer preview account from outlook. But still it is not possible to communicate. I already mentioned it clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only connect to the specific account that you got from the Outlook Dev team via the Outlook REST APIs.  You won't be able to connect to accounts that have not yet been enabled for the Outlook.com preview.

We are working as fast as we can to get everyone enabled, but for the time being you'd need to test and develop only against that account we gave you, and other accounts that have been moved over.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know, when this feature will be live? Because I already started development.